# Pull a remote branch from Github

Tags: git, github

I'm using a Github repo master branch.

A fix exists in another branch which for some reason it hasn't been pushed to master:

https://github.com/ftexchange/ftx/pull/13

I'd like to obtain this fix branch (arf-labs-ou:openssl-1.1) in my local repo.

I've tried `git branch -a` and `git branch -r` to find `arf-labs-ou:openssl-1.1` but neither show it.

How do I checkout/pull/obtain this branch?

Comment: Did you try using checkout command? `git checkout arf-labs-ou:openssl-1.1` ?

Comment: @Chetan Yea. I got "error: pathspec 'arf-labs-ou:openssl-1.1' did not match any file(s) known to git". I presume this is because Git cannot "see" the branch, hence it doesn't show when i run git branch -a or git branch -r

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The PR / fix is not yet merged, apparently because it has some problems, but you can still fetch the commit in question from GitHub in various ways.  Having done so, the syntax for extracting that particular *version* of the *entire file* is not:

```
git checkout arf-labs-ou:openssl-1.1
```

(as seen in [Chetan's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72371140/pull-a-remote-branch-from-github#comment127852237_72371140)), but rather:

```
git checkout <hash> -- <path>
```

or:

```
git restore --source <hash> -- <path>
```

The commit hash ID containing the update is `60bf8afd64bbdcad0f011153cff27a6faefe86a5` (you can find this by clicking around on GitHub); there are multiple files affected.

If you wish, you can attach a name—branch or tag name—to the commit, e.g.:

```
git branch pr13 60bf8afd64bbdcad0f011153cff27a6faefe86a5
```

You must first fetch their commit, of course; it's available under the name `refs/pull/13/head` in the repository in which the pull request was made, i.e., https://github.com/ftexchange/ftx.  You can fetch this commit *and* give it a branch name all at once:

```
git fetch https://github.com/ftexchange/ftx refs/pull/13/head:refs/heads/pr13
```

and now you can `git show pr13` to view their commit locally, rather than looking at it on GitHub.

Note that `arf-labs-ou:openssl-1.1` is a *GitHub-specific* name pattern by which GitHub can look up the various repositories and other names found exclusively on GitHub.  This string is not useful elsewhere.

Answer (score 0):

Step 1
`git checkout .` - To clear your local of any uncommitted changes

Step 2
`git fetch` - Get all branches from remote

Step 3
`git checkout arf-labs-ou:openssl-1.1` - Checkout the specific branch you want

Comment: Thanks for your answer. When I run `git checkout arf-labs-ou:openssl-1.1` I get `error: pathspec 'arf-labs-ou:openssl-1.1' did not match any file(s) known to git`